# HTML: Hyperlink to current directory?

Tags: php, html, css, hyperlink

I am on the page.

```
en/section/page.ext
```

I want to link the anchor to `en/section`, but I not want to write neither `en` nor `section` in the link. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a relative link.

```
<a href=".">Current directory</a>
```

The above will link to the root of the current directory, so if you click it from `en/section/page.ext`, you will be send to `/en/section/`.